# Create a copy of a column for a matrix template C++

Tags: c++11, templates, matrix

I am learning C++11 and I would like to create copies of columns for a simple matrix template I created. I don't want to use full-fledged matrix templates like armadillo and others because I don't need sofisticated matrix algebra. The operations I would like to do are:

```
matrix<int> A(3,3,{1,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,1});
matrix<int> A1(3,1));
A1 = A.col_cpy(1);

// do something with the column vector
A1[2] += 5;

// and then assign back 
A.col(1) = A1;
```

my naive first attempt with col_cpy was to return a column matrix which is wrong because the local variable is destroyed.

```
template<typename T >
class matrix {
  T* m_elems;
  size_t m_rows;
  size_t m_cols;

public:
   matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols)
: m_elems((T*)std::malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(T))), m_rows(rows), m_cols(cols) {}

matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, std::initializer_list<T> const& xs)
: m_elems((T*)std::malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(T))), m_rows(rows), m_cols(cols) {
T* es = m_elems;
for (auto x : xs) {
  *es = x;
  ++es;
 }
}

auto col_cpy(size_t col) const -> T* {
 auto c = (T*)std::malloc(m_rows * sizeof(T));
  col_cpy(col, c);
 return c;
}


auto col_cpy(size_t col) const -> matrix& {
  matrix <T> c(m_rows,1);
  for(auto i=0u; i<m_rows; i++)
      c(i) = m_elems[col * m_rows + i];

 return c;
}
```

Another way was to create a friend function and pass matrix by reference

```
template<typename T>
void col_cpy( size_t col, matrix<T> const& D, matrix<T> & A ) {
   A(D.m_rows,1);
   D.col_cpy(col,A.m_elems);

}
```

So I could do

```
col_cpy(1,A,A1);
```

It works but I think is not the safest neither elegant way to do it.

The full example is here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/546db2c1b520bdc7

Comment: Why can't you just return by value? That would be better in every way, is there a specific reason why you can't?

Comment: Silly, I didn't realise that I can.